# Is the change in Kinetic Energy not equal to the work done when mass changes at some rate?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, mass, power

[image: Just as in this question]

Here the Rate of change in Kinetic energy is not equal to the the power. Please explain

Comment: The shorter answer: power is force times AVERAGE speed. Here the speed is not constant.  The answer of @pasaba shows this in detail.

Comment: Can you give a citation where this problem came from?

Comment: Not from any particular textbook but it is a question from the material of an institute I attend for the preparation of NEET( National Eligibility cum Entrance Test). NEET is an exam in India for admissions in Medical Colleges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official answer to point (ii) is not correct. Proof (counterexample):

Note: I will write as $V$ uppercase the final water speed.

In an interval $T$ an amount of water $\rho A V T$ must be accelerated from $0$ to $V$. Assuming it is done with a constant acceleration $V/T$ then:

$$F=ma=(\rho A V T) (V/T)=\rho A V^2$$

$$displacement = x = \frac{1}{2} (V/T) T^2=\frac{1}{2} VT$$ (here the official answer made a mistake, it fix $x=VT$)

$$work = W = Fx = (\rho A V^2) (\frac{1}{2} VT) = \frac{1}{2} \rho A V^3 T$$

$$power=W/T=\frac{1}{2} \rho A V^3$$

With these results, there are not mismatch between the calculus by energy and by force.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I must disagree with @pasaba por aqui's answer.  The textbook answer given in the OP is correct - the power provided is twice the gain in KE of the stream.  The other half of the power is dissipated.  This is sometimes known as the "conveyor belt paradox," because a similar setup where it arises is the case of sand being deposited with zero speed onto a conveyor belt moving at constant speed $\text{v}$.  The force that must be applied to the belt is $\dot{m}\text{v}$, and the power to drive the belt is $\dot{m}\text{v}^2$, while the rate of increase of KE of the sand is only $\frac{1}{2}\dot{m}\text{v}^2$.  For a good explanation of *why* half the power gets dissipated (at least in the case of the sand), if you have access, see [this article](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.2342862)   (F. S. Crawford, *The Physics Teacher* **27**, 546 (1989)).